# Windows firewall allow connect to only 1 IP on machine with multiple IPs

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

My server has multiple IPs (e.g. 40.1.25.23 - 40.1.25.27). How can I configure windows firewall so that an inbound request to only one of the IPs will be allowed. (e.g. 40.1.25.25)

Comment: What windows version do you use?

Comment: windows server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to allow incoming connection to one ip alone in case of multiple NIC.

1.Click the start button and then search with the word  Windows Firewall with Advanced security keyword to open the firewall with advanced security.

2.Once the windows is open then click on the Inbound Rules on the left side,Now it would ask various inputs.

3.Fill the steps like Rules,program,Protocol and Ports.

4.Now in the Scope wizard,please give the ip 40.1.25.25  for these ip address column  under which local ip address does this rule apply? and then complete whole process.